# Estimation of parameters through multivariate Taylor expansion?

Tags: taylor-series, estimation-theory

I do have a function $$f(t) = \prod\limits_{j=1}^{n} \left(1 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} M_{i,j} t_i\right)^{-\alpha_{j}}$$ defined by parameters:

- $M_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}_{+}, \;\forall  i \in 1,...,d,\; \forall j \in 1,...,n$
- $\alpha_j \in \mathbb{R}_{+}, \; \forall j \in 1,...,n$

over $\mathbb{C}^{d}$ (but i'm mainly interested in the $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{d}$ restriction).

Suppose that I pick a suitable $t^{*}$ (say, inside the radius of convergence), and that I have observations of values of the derivatives up to a certain number of derivations $N$ :

$$g_m = f^{(m)}(t^{*}), \; \forall m \in \mathbb{N}^d, \sum_{i=1}^{d}m_i \le N$$

Can I, through a Taylor expansion around $t^{*}$, estimate parameters $M,\alpha$ from the observations $g_m$? I guess that if I have a lot of them (say $N$ is very big), i could do it. On the over hand, I don't know precisely how much I do need compared to $n,d$. Furthermore, I do not know how to do this estimation.

Could you help me a little?